# where is the getoutputstream method of httpservletresponse in java?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

When transferring large files, I find the stream retrieved by the response.getoutputstream () method. What is the final output direction of this OutputStream? Does it take up server memory?

```
OutputStream toClient = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: `Does it take up server memory?` Since you wrap it in a `BufferedOutputStream`, yes, it will buffer some bytes in memory.

Comment: The bytes you write to this stream go to the network socket that the servlet container uses to communicate with the browser. Unless you have some filter doing it, they're not stored in the server memory (except for the small buffering that BufferedOutputStream, and potentially the underlying stream use), and you can thus send a large number of bytes without worry.